# How to define a static placeholder in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a parameter which should **set at the beginning of each epoch** and it is **constant** during the epoch's execution. Currently, we defined a placeholder for this param and during the training I have to pass the same value in each iteration:

```
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={param: const_param})
```

It's a bit inefficient since pass the same value at each step of the same epoch. Is it possible to define a placeholder and feed it **once** just at the beginning of each epoch?

Comment: Use `tf.constant()` directly?

Comment: I think you might be able make a new collection of variables -- like tf.local_variables -- and then reset the collection at the end of each epoch and initialize to the desired value.

Comment: Its not a clean solution! Placeholders should have a feeding schedule.